# Can I get My original profile Linkedin image without linkedin logo?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I can get the original profile image via using picture-urls::(original).

But This Image contains linkedin logo at bottom, and I want the image without that logo.

[image]

```
String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,email-address,last-name,headline,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),industry,summary,specialties,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer)?format=json";
```

Please help me for this

Comment: Is the image always be in that size? then it would be easy to crop by just adding some offset. For sure the linked logo is not allowed to remove.

Comment: If i got this directly from linkedin then if will be Great

Comment: Just crop the the image without including a portion of bottom part.

Comment: but i just passed url direct to our server in case of linkedin sync